# Does PHP Support Arrow Function Syntax?

Tags: php, arrow-functions

After complaining about the tumultuous task of writing the keyword `function` over and over, I asked someone about an easier way. The person said that PHP is going to have arrow function syntax similar to es6.

```js
const foo = (x, y) => {
    return x + y;
};
```

As I continued to look into this, I have not been able to find many examples online.

Can someone of the right caliber please expound upon this?

At this point, I am also really interested in how this would fit into the OOP aspect of PHP.

Comment: I think you have been downvoted because your question is a bit open and it has two separated questions. You should only make one question and they need to be a bit more specific, for example, "Does exist this functionality in PHP?". The second question is also too broad for StackOverflow, maybe is better for https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Original answer from February 2018:

This appears to be the syntax described in https://wiki.php.net/rfc/arrow_functions. It does have an experimental implementation.

In the arrow functions proposal, it is mentioned that it's an alternative to the "short closures" proposal, https://wiki.php.net/rfc/short_closures

As of February 2018, the current versions of PHP are 7.1.4 / 7.2.2.

I can't find any confirmation that either proposal has been approved. The former is in the "Under Discussion" state, the latter is "Declined / Withdrawn in favor of http://wiki.php.net/rfc/arrow_functions". I think it's too soon to know whether it will be adopted in any future version of PHP.

---

Update December 2019:

The feature has been released in PHP 7.4, according to https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration74.new-features.php

> Arrow functions provide a shorthand syntax for defining functions with
>   implicit by-value scope binding.
>
> ```
> <?php
> $factor = 10;
> $nums = array_map(fn($n) => $n * $factor, [1, 2, 3, 4]);
> ```

But the usage has not been updated yet in the PHP manual page about [Anonymous Functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)

Here's a blog going into detail: https://stitcher.io/blog/short-closures-in-php

Comment: also, see https://wiki.php.net/rfc/arrow_function_preference - it seems there's an RFC coming for 7.2 about it... maybe we'll *finally* see it one day.

Comment: There is a new RFC which aims for PHP 7.4. You can find it here: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/arrow_functions_v2.

Comment: So after discussing the feature for four years, they have a third RFC. Maybe by 2030 they will have it implemented in a released product.

Comment: @BillKarwin the RFC mentioned above was accepted and will be implemented in the PHP 7.4

Comment: It's here in 2019.

Answer (score 12):

Yes. The new RFC has been accepted for PHP 7.4 https://wiki.php.net/rfc/arrow_functions_v2

Answer (score 6):

Based on RFC for **PHP 7.4** code could look like

```
$users->map(
    fn($user) => $user->first_name.' '.$user->last_name
);
```

instead of

```
$users->map(function($user) {
    return $user->first_name.' '.$user->last_name;
});
```

Comment: Congrats Dude, your code is on laravel-news https://laravel-news.com/short-arrow-functions